# Is it good practice to construct class names in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a section of code which is similar to this:

```
if (a == 'info') {
    $("#abc").addClass('abc-info');
} else if (a == 'warning') {
    $("#abc").addClass('abc-warning');
}
```

I got a suggestion to replace the above code with something like this:

```
addClassToABC(a)

function addClassToABC(type) {
    $("#abc").addClass('abc-' + type);
}
```

But is it a good practice to split class/id names like this - "'abc' + type" because I see this can become a nightmare for anyone debugging/refactoring this code to locate a particular class/id name.

Comment: Seems completely reasonable. After all that is exactly what `$.fn.addClass` is doing.

Comment: Be careful -- these are not functionally equivalent. The first snippet validates that the input value is a certain string before calling `.addClass()` while the second snippet does not perform input validation.

Comment: Creating dynamic classnames isn't unusual at all, but whether or not it's the best solution for a given usecase depends explicitly on the usecase.

Comment: As for your "refactoring nightmare" argument, it would also be a nightmare to locate every occurrence of a certain string and update it in the future if it's hardcoded in several places as in your first example.

Comment: I agree with you neha, debugging would be a problem in future.

Comment: It depends on context and according to your first snippet, I would use `$("#abc").addClass('abc-'+a);`.

Comment: if you want to create classes dynamically use a js- prefix if it is only used by js